# How can I access Firebase data under a childByAutoID?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to access some book data that was put into my database under a random child ID. I've been scouring other questions, but the farthest I've gotten is being able to access the ID within a closure. I can't figure out how to properly set up a completion handler to extract the ID.

Also, I don't know if there's a much easier way to be going about this?

Here's the data I'm trying to access:
[Firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9oIn.png)

[image]

And here's my current code that needs a completion handler, I think?

```
func getChildID(department: String, course: String) {

        let parentRef = myDatabase.child("departments").child(department).child(course)

        parentRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (courseSnapshot) in
            if let data = courseSnapshot.value as? [String:String] {

                for value in data {
                    let isbn = value.value
                    if isbn != "ISBN" {

                        myDatabase.child("listings").child("\(isbn)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                            let dictionary = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
                            for key in dictionary.keyEnumerator() {
                                let myKey = key as! String
                                return
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It appears that each listing in the listings node is unique? If that's true you wouldn't need to create another child under each one. Alternately The children of the listings node could be created with childByAutoId and the listing number would be a child of that; something like */listings/autoid/listing_number: "97801..."*

Comment: The second child by autoID is so that I can have multiple listings if the same book, with different data in conditions or price, etc. It's definitely a funky structure though. The ISBN at the top is so that users can search by ISBN along with some other stuff.

Comment: Totally makes sense. An issue you may run into is querying over multiple listings. The childbyAutoId nodes are sorta too deep, although it can still be done via a deep path query, it would be better to denormalize the data. The structure I suggested in my question would be one option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go. An answer to the question. However, and I mentioned in my comment to the question, the structure could be improved. However, there may be more children under each listing child so this answer handles it.

This just print's each authors name but it shows how to get to it so the answer should be expanded for the other child nodes.

```
let listingsRef = self.ref.child("listings")
listingsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let autoIdSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
        for autoChild in autoIdSnap.children {
            let childSnap = autoChild as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = childSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            let author = dict["author"] as! String
            print(author)
        }
    }
})
```

Oh, and a better structure may be

```
listings
   childByAutoId
      author: "Some author"
      listing: 9780184888
   childByAutoId
      author: "Another author"
      listing: 9799292598
```

Edit: If there will only ever be one and only one childByAutoId under each listing, you can eliminate the loop in the above and do this

```
let listingsRef = self.ref.child("listings")
listingsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let autoIdSnap = child as! DataSnapshot //each listing
        let childDict = autoIdSnap.value as! [String: Any] //a dict of items within the listing
        let firstKey = childDict.keys.first! //the key to the first item
        let valuesDict = childDict[firstKey] as! [String: Any] //the values for that key
        let author = valuesDict["author"] as! String //the author value
        print(author)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can observe changes in the last object before the childByAutoId(), in this case it would be "listings", and then create a model out of it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (user, error) in
        if error == nil{
            print("sign in successful")
        }
    }

    let query = myDatabase.child("listings")

    query?.removeAllObservers()

    query?.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            let booksSnapshot = Books(snap: snapshot)

            for children in booksSnapshot.books{
                let childByAutoId = children.value as! NSDictionary

                for books in childByAutoId{
                    let key = books.value as! NSDictionary

                    let book: Books = Books(fromJson: JSON())

                    book.author = key["author"] as! String
                    book.title = key["title"] as! String
                    book.price = key["price"] as! Int

                    print(book.price)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

//Model 
//Note: you will have to install the 'SwiftyJSON' to create this model

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
import Firebase

class Books : NSObject{

var author : String!
var title : String!
var price : Int! // you can add more variables later
var books : [String: AnyObject]!

init(fromJson json: JSON!){
    if json.isEmpty{
        return
    }
    author = json["author"].stringValue
    title = json["title"].stringValue
    price = json["price"].intValue
}

/**
 * Instantiate the instance using the passed json values to set the properties values
 */
init(snap: DataSnapshot){
    let json = snap.value as! NSDictionary
    books = json as! [String: AnyObject]
}
}
```

Comment: Whoa... hold up. The OP is asking about the */listings* node, not departments. Also, this code won't work with the listings node because there's a child under each listing. Additionally this code is non-functional as that's not a valid query, if that's what the intention was. There's no reason to remove all observers before adding that observer. Also, .value observers read in the entire node so the children must be iterated over. Can you fix this code?

Comment: You can just change the departments to listing, my bad, and once u created the object u can access all of its child attributes

Comment: Sure, i just wasnt with a firebase database in front of me so it was kinda hard..ill create one and fix the code

Comment: Seems like a lot of extraneous code and it will loose the ordering of the data. So even if the data was queried with .orderBy that would get lost because the snapshot data is it put into a dictionary. Also, it requires a third party library to be installed which is really unnecessary.

Comment: dude, i wasnt the one who created the structure of this database, in my opinion the structure is wrong, but the guy didn't ask for my opinion on the sturcture, he asked for help to get the objects inside, and this is what i gave him, simple as that.

Comment: I got you. Just thinking it should be simpler. Looks like it works though so that's a start!

Comment: you are more than welcome to offer another solution + tell him how to improve his structure

Comment: I'll second that! Your opinion is more than welcome @Jay

Comment: tim_d, you don't have to accept my answer, but if it at least worked for you i will appreciate an upvote

Comment: I appreciate all responses Arie Pinto! I've upvoted yours, but I don't think it shows publicly as I still don't have many permissions unlocked.

Comment: Thank you, i also upvotes you question and the accepted answer who seems really cool. Cheers too yall :)